# Compare two identical sql tables by a condition

Tags: sql

Say I have two tables that look something like this:

`Table1` has columns **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**

`Table2` has the same columns as `Table 1`

**A** has the exact same data for both tables. **B** is equals to `1` for all rows for `Table1` and `2` for all rows for `Table2`.

Both tables have the exact same number rows. How would I create a query that outputs the corresponding value in **A** for rows where `Table1.C > Table2.C`?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please tag appropriate RDMBS.

Comment: did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    tableA.a
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.a = tableB.a
WHERE tableA.c > tableB.c
```

You're going to want to join the two on the value that will always be static, and then evaluate from there.

Comment: The `JOIN` is wrong. The A columns are equivalent. You cannot join on column B because he said they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If column A has same data in both the tables then assuming it can be used as a joining factor you can get the corresponding rows in both the tables and then compare value of column C to display only tuples from table1 that has value greater than corresponding value of column C in table2.

```
SELECT T1.A, T1.C, T2,C 
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.A = T2.A
WHERE T1.C > T2.C
```

I am displaying value of column C from both the tables just for debugging purpose to ensure value of column C in table1 is greater than that in table2